# Can't start React app with Vite on Heroku: `concurrently: not found`

Tags: reactjs, heroku, vite, postcss

My react app fails to start when running in Heroku. I am using Luke McDonald's startup page located here: https://github.com/lukemcdonald/holly-react

Here is what my `package.json` scripts section looks like:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:css && vite build",
    "build:css": "postcss styles/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles.css",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run dev:css\" \"vite\"",
    "dev:css": "postcss styles/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles.css --watch",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run dev:css\" \"vite\"",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
```

When I push to heroku, the *build* succeeds. But it to fail to start:

```
app[web.1]: /tmp/start-497558d9.sh: 1: concurrently: not found
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I added concurrently to my dependencies, to no avail

```json
"dependencies": {
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "scrollreveal": "^4.0.9",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
```

Comment: Concurrently, like all dev dependencies, won't be installed in the final slug. But also you shouldn't be running in dev mode on Heroku.

Comment: `concurrently` is both a dev dependency and a dependency. Because it is also included as a dependency, shouldn't it be installed in final slug?

How *should* I run this in prod, if the dev command script is `concurrently \"npm run dev:css\" \"vite\"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to run `concurrently \"npm run dev:css\" \"vite\"` on Heroku. That command is intended for development environments (such as your local machine).

You are likely trying to serve the **production build** of your app, which does not require `concurrently` at all. Just run `npm run preview`, which runs `vite preview`, which -- as of Vite 3 -- uses [`sirv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sirv) to serve the build output directory.

However, you don't necessarily need to use `vite preview`. You could use any other HTTP server pointed at the build output directory (e.g., [`zeit/serve`](https://github.com/zeit/serve) or [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)).